# How to make a method return IEnumerable<T> from array?

Tags: c#

I have a method like below. Instead of `yield return` I need to store the values in an array and need to return it as IEnumerable. How can I achieve this?..Thanks for your help

```
public static IEnumerable<UserData> DetailsFactory
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new UserData(
                    "Jim",
                    "Parker",
                    "Sheryl")
                    .SetName("User-1 Address details") as UserData;
            }
        }
```

Comment: just return the array

Comment: Why are you using `yield`? There's nothing to enumerate there. Just `return new[] { ... }`.

Comment: FYI this code is not valid and will not compile. There could not be any `get {}` in method only in properties.

Comment: @Fabjan This _is_ a property.

Comment: @RenéVogt It is, but `yield return` in property is rather weird...

Comment: @Fabjan: What's weird about it? It may be unusual, as properties often don't dynamically generate items in an `IEnumerable<T>`, but it's perfectly valid to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `T[]` is already an `IEnumerable<T>`. So you can just return an array directly:

```
return new[] {
  new UserData(
                "Jim",
                "Parker",
                "Sheryl")
                .SetName("User-1 Address details")
}
```

Comment: Side note: Yes, someone could cast the result to `UserData[]` and modify it, but trying to defend against people doing stupid things that are not guaranteed to work is a futile effort in my eyes. Even by wrapping the array in another `IEnumerable` you can use reflection to get at the original array. There is no way of foolproofing an API against an adversary who doesn't care about the limitations posed by the type system.

Comment: you can wrap the array in a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` if you want to avoid that (however that would not answer the question, which you answered perfectly well ;-) ). I don't think you can get the original array from a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (I may be wrong, though)... then again, you could always reconstruct the array (on a new array) from any enumerable :-)

Comment: @Jcl: If `ReadOnlyCollection` copies the items you can't get at the original array, but it only [wraps the original collection](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/readonlycollection.cs,64e45c8a9b38b1c2). And then you can get at it via reflection. I think the normal protection from the type system is fine. There isn't much use in trying to defend against hostile developers IMHO.

Comment: I hadn't seen the implementation of `ReadOnlyCollection`, but most definitely, yes. About the rest of the comment: 100% agreed :-)